# How to display aggregation in UML diagram generated by Doxygen for C++ source?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to generate UML diagram for 2 very simple classes. The diagram should display composition(class B is composed of class A). However, Composition is not displayed in html documentation generated by doxygen.

I believe there is some option in Doxyfile that should be enabled, but so far I have not found which one it is.
Note that class inheritance is displayed properly. But I assume that doxygen should know how to draw composition and aggregation as well.

```
//a.h
class A{ char a; };

//b.h
#include "a.h"
class B{ A a; };
```

I expect to see a filled diamond from B to A in class diagram generated by Doxygen, but it not there.
Here are some of the extract options set in Doxyfile

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
```

Doxygen version is 1.8.16

Comment: AFAIK, Doxygen cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with UML_LOOK = YES

Comment: How does your result look like? Which version of doxygen did you use? Any other settings (e.g. `HAVE_DOT`)? Please show result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Comment: It looks like normal uml with not filled diamonds. The version, I will check tomorrow in my kubuntu 18.04 let's env. About other settings can be said that collaboration diagrams should be activated additionaly.

Comment: I mean kubuntu 18.04 LTS environment with default installation of doxygen

Comment: My Doxygen Version is 1.8.13. For showing version, use 'doxygen -v' not -x

Comment: That doxygen version is quite old (December 29, 2016), the current doxygen version is 1.10.0

Comment: Good. Should work too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).